# fromFetch operator does not reset cache on unsubscribe

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

I will provide two version of code snippet for better understaing:

1st one

```
const test = timer(0, 1000).pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }));

const subscription1 = test.subscribe(
  (value) => console.log('Subscription 1:', value),
  (error) => console.error(error),
  () => console.log('Subscription 1 completed'),
);

setTimeout(() => {
  subscription1.unsubscribe();
}, 6000);

setTimeout(() => {
  const subscription2 = test.subscribe(
    (value) => console.log('Subscription 2:', value),
    (error) => console.error(error),
    () => console.log('Subscription 2 completed'),
  );
}, 10000);
```

Main point of this code is to test how `shareReply` works with `refCount` set to `true`. Behaviour is expected, since
`subscription1` observable emits 5 times, then I unsubscribe, meaning `refCount` will be 0 again for `test`, what causes `test` observable to drop the cache. When i subscribe with `subscription2` the emission start with 0.

But if i use `fromFetch` operator, cache of `test` observable is not dropped, even if there are no active subscribers to test observable:

```
export const groupsRaw$ = fromFetch('/some_endpoint').pipe(
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }),
);

const subscription1 = groupsRaw$.subscribe(
  (value) => console.log('Subscription 1:', value),
  (error) => console.error(error),
  () => console.log('Subscription 1 completed'),
);

setTimeout(() => {
  subscription1.unsubscribe();
}, 6000);

setTimeout(() => {
  const subscription2 = groupsRaw$.subscribe(
    (value) => console.log('Subscription 2:', value),
    (error) => console.error(error),
    () => console.log('Subscription 2 completed'),
  );
}, 10000);
```

There will be only one request in the network tab.

I expect that `subscription2` on subscribe should refetch data, but it takes it from cache. But cache should be already dropped. What do i miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing doesn't have to do with using `fromFetch` vs `timer`, it has to do with the source completing vs not completing.

`shareReplay` will cache the source observable for future subscribers if its source completes. (*see [this github issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5029) for reference*).

To achieve your desired behavior, you can use [`share`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share) and specify `resetOnComplete = true`:

```js
  share({
    connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
    resetOnComplete     : true,
    resetOnRefCountZero : true,
  })
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75960357?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts) you can play around with.

---

Since all the "reset" options are `true` by default, you don't actually need to specify them. So you could simply do:

```js
  share({ connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1) })
```

Comment: Currently I'm using rxjs 6, I've tried to use share(), without any parameters, since I cannot pass them in current version. Not sure if I get the same behaviour as in the code you've written above, but it works.